# Fixing browser addon/extension reputation issue

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

My firefox addon and chrome extension showing some wired error on avast antivirus. It shows following error message.
"we have identified multiple browser add-ons that have a bad reputation among avast users".
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: List out your addons that will help us help you. I havent heard of firefox addons haveing bad rep, i know for a fact, it was in the news too that multiple google chrome extensions were hijacked.

Comment: @PrashantShukla In fact, your addon *does* show undesirable activity. On every page visit, you're sending a request to an external http server (not even https) and (depending on the reply) unconditionally insert an iframe in the document. An improvement could be to not show the frame by default, but use a [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) icon to show whether coupons are available and only show the iframe when the user clicks on it.

Comment: @RobW How does avast maintain user reputation? Is it user generated(based on ratings)? or Avast internally apply some sort of algorithm.

Comment: @PrashantShukla I don't know, my comments are based on my review of your source code.

Comment: Ok thanks not an issue.